# Getting error on invalid xpath, but able to hit the element while inspecting on browser

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Getting the error of invalid slection: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression as following xpath is in valid.

```
private @FindBy(xpath = "//h1[contains(text(), 'Discover World')]")
WebElement elementSearch;
```

I even tried with using normalize-space, but with no luck. The action is simple, extract and test out whether the element assigned with the xpath above isDisplayed via Boolean.

The method with the implementation:

```
public Boolean elementText(WebElement element) {
    getDriver().findElement(By.xpath(String.valueOf(element)));
    System.out.println("Status of Element present " + element.isDisplayed());
    return null;
}
```

The method calling this implementation:

```
public void verifyPageLaunched() {
    elementText(elementSearch);
}
```

All actions results in invalid xpath expression error only when running the test on the browser but while manually checking the xpath on browser 'inspect' - it trigger's the right element. Also checked but the above element is not within any iframe either.

Any suggestions what could be triggering this? Thanks team

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```java
public Boolean elementText(WebElement element) {
    getDriver().findElement(By.xpath(String.valueOf(element)));
    System.out.println("Status of Element present " + element.isDisplayed());
    return null;
}
```

You are passing an object of type `WebElement`.
Then you trying to apply `String.valueOf(element)` on that `element` object of type `WebElement`.
So, it clearly will not work!
`WebElement` element is not a number, like int so you could apply `String.valueOf(element)` on it!
That's why the result of `String.valueOf(element)` is definitely NOT a valid XPath expression!
**UPD**
Instead of what you are doing you can do any of the following:

1. Passing a `WebElement` object

```java
public Boolean isElementDisplayed(WebElement element) {
    System.out.println("Status of Element present " + element.isDisplayed());
    return element.isDisplayed();
}
```

2. Passing a `By`

```java
public Boolean isElementDisplayed(By by) {
    boolean displayed = getDriver().findElement(by).isDisplayed();
    System.out.println("Status of Element present " + displayed);
    return displayed;
}
```

3. Passing XPath String expression

```java
public Boolean isElementDisplayed(String xpath) {
    boolean displayed = getDriver().findElement(By.xpath(xpath)).isDisplayed();
    System.out.println("Status of Element present " + displayed);
    return displayed;
}
```

Comment: Then should I make the parameter type for the method from WebElement to String? Because doing will make the calling method to have xpath defined as By instead of WebElement.

Comment: I have added more explanations with examples

Comment: #1 worked, I understand the issue now. I was incorrectly casting WebElement and String to get the thing working. Thanks @Prophet, appreciate your prompt responses man.

Comment: You are welcome, my friend!